# Function calls are not supported

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using 
`@angular: 4.3.6`
`@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.10`
`@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.10`
`@angular/cli: "^1.4.1`

and I am getting the below error whenever I try to `ng serve`.

```
ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. 
Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 194:50 in the original .ts file), 
resolving symbol NgModule in d:/projects/webclient/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, 
resolving symbol CoreModule in d:/projects/webclient/src/core/core.module.ts, 
resolving symbol CoreModule in d:/projects/webclient/src/core/core.module.ts
```

I don't have any lambda functions used or exported in the below `CoreModule`.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { NgReduxModule, NgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { applyMiddleware, Store, combineReducers, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';

import { SharedModule } from 'shared/shared.module';

import { routes } from './core.routes';

import { STORE_PROVIDER, IAppState } from 'core/models/store';
import * as r from 'core/reducers';
import * as c from './components';
import * as v from './views';
import * as s from './services';
import { MenuAction, MenuGroup, MenuItem } from 'core/models';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgReduxModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    c.AppbarComponent,
    v.AppComponent,
    v.SettingsComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: STORE_PROVIDER, useValue: r.sidebar, multi: true },
    { provide: STORE_PROVIDER, useValue: r.actionbar, multi: true },
    { provide: STORE_PROVIDER, useValue: r.tabs, multi: true },
    s.ActionbarService,
    s.SidebarService,
    s.TabsService,
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor( @Inject(STORE_PROVIDER) storeProviders: any[], ngRedux: NgRedux<{}>,
    actionbarService: s.ActionbarService, sidebarService: s.SidebarService) {
    ngRedux.configureStore(r.generateRootReducer(storeProviders), {}, [createLogger()]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The error likely refers to NgModule code, `r.generateRootReducer(storeProviders)` in particular.

Comment: @estus I commented the whole constructor but with no luck; I even removed the `r` import.

Comment: But it does not say in which file. The CoreModule file is only 52 lines. So if you are saying it's in line 50 and not 194, then I should look for character 194 which does not exist because there are only 89 characters in line 50.

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3854 . The case is likely specific to your setup and the way it works with angular-cli, not to Angular and AOT in general. Consider providing a way to reproduce the problem. A repo would probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was a `tsconfig` misconfiguration. In my main module I was importing the `CoreModule` using absolute path (i.e. `root/core/core.module` instead of `../core/core.module`). Basically I was missing the `baseUrl` from the `tsconfig.app.json` file.

I don't understand why this was happening for two reasons (and please if someone can explain to me):

1. This is not a new project and it was working before.
2. The `tsconfig.app.json` is extending from the main `tsconfig.json` file which already has the proper `baseUrl`set in it.

Anyways, I hope this help other people who have the same issue.